# Decision tree has 2 similar nodes

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, supervised-learning

I have created a decision tree using sklearn.

```
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Parameters in dataframe X are - `'Company size'`, `'Industry_other'`, `'Account size'`, `'Country'`, and `'Use case 1'`.

I am getting 2 similar nodes when trying to visualize the tree using `export_graphviz`:

[image: output from export_graphviz]

What is the reason for getting similar nodes? How do I read this tree?

Comment: You have this nodes on the same level, so everything is OK. This only means, that for `Industry_Other` both greater and lesser than 0.5 the decision rule for the `Company size` (`<= 1.5`) are the same.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the explanation I'll explain it with letters. Your tree looks like this:

```
A -> B
|
 \-> C -> D -> F
     |     \-> G
     |
      \-> E -> H
           \-> I
```

With `A` being your *root* node and `D` and `E` the nodes that you say are *similar nodes*.

In your diagram, the node `A` is split in two, `B` and `C`. Data samples with `Account size < 19969` go to C and otherwise to `B`.

Among the samples that arrive to `C`, the ones with `Industry other <= 1.5` go to `E` and others go to `D`. Here, `E` and `D` look identical because they have learn the same rule, but that rule is applied to different data samples.

This is, from the samples that arrive to `E`, the ones with `company size < 1.5` go to `I` and others to `H`, and something similar applies to `D`.

Hope it is more clear and I didn't confuse you more.

Essentially, they have learn the same rule, but apply it to different samples. In other words, both `D` and `E` have learnt that the best rule to separate in two sets the samples that arrive to them is the same. However, the samples that arrive to them have different nature (different `Industry_other` to be precise).

It can also somehow be understood as that `Company_size` helps to discriminate between samples regardless of their `Industry_other`.